# Sharing large data across gunicorn workers

Tags: python, docker, performance, memory, gunicorn

I am comparing 2 approaches of sharing data for performance. Both approaches work functionally but differ largely in performance.

Approach 1. copy-on-write : use gunicorn preload_app=True and define a 30Gb list in flask app so that it can be shared among all gunicorn workers. there is 1 container running this app.

The container memory usage is around 31Gb/251 Gb.
I observe that the overall performance is degraded. Some http request from this app to other services take too much time.

Approach 2: Store the 30Gb data in a separate container on same host.

Container 1: main app (1 Gb)

Container 2: redis cache (30Gb)

The main app doesn't have any shared variables holding large data. Instead the data is held in separate redis container (though using the memory of the same host)
This approach gives much better performance (elapsed time reduction by 4-5 times)

What is not clear to me is, how are the two approaches different?
If the total used memory of the host is same ,why performances are so different

I tried to search a lot about whether holding lar data in variables affect app performance but couldn't find anything.

Profiling for Approach 1:

[image]

Comment: Have you used any sort of profiler to understand where the time is going?  My intuition is that the in-process store will be faster, but if you're losing a lot of time to garbage collection or if the CoW semantics are implemented in Python proper I could see it being slower.  When you access the data, do you need the whole thing, or are you selecting fragments of the data via Redis commands?

Comment: I have edited my question to add image for profile for approach 1